# Currently achievable spatial resolution in photon detectors?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, experimental-technique

Suppose one wants some 2D detector that measures the positions of photons incoming transverse to the detector; something like an array of photomultipliers. What kind of spatial resolutions are achievable these days, especially when the energy of the incident photons is already known?

For example, in a double-slit experiment done using photons, how well can one spatially resolve the interference pattern on the screen, and what kind of technology would be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic tools of the high-resolution photon detection business are [silicon photon-multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_photomultiplier), [multi-channel plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microchannel_plate_detector), crossed [scintilating fiber](https://www.google.com/search?q=scintillating%20fiber%20optics&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) planes, various [drift chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_chamber#Drift_chambers) designs (an old standby for which much practical experience exists; relatively inexpensive but less turn-key than other options.), or if you don't mind a modest quantum efficiency plain old CCD and CMOS light detectors like those found in digital cameras.

Resolutions are in the neighborhood of $10\,\mathrm{\mu m}$ or a little less for MCPs, $20$ or more $\mathrm{\mu m}$ for SiPMTs, and about $4\,\mathrm{\mu m}$  for a particular CMOS camera sensor that I am familar with (they come smaller than that, but I frankly doubt it is to your advantage in most applications). Scintillating fiber resolution is limited by the fiber size, but I don't know off the top of my head what ranges are available. I've seen and handled circa $2\,\mathrm{mm}$ scintillating fiber, but I suspect it comes finer than that.